# Check if user likes my fb fanpage

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-like

I am trying to make a js script that will check if someone likes my fanpage or not.
I have tried many things, but none have worked. Can any of you give me a link or write a detailed instruction how to do this? 
My current code:

```js
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '180255582485080',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
setTimeout(function(){
FB.api('/me/likes?fields=id', function(response) {
    var our_page_id = '1775956295985318';
    var user_is_fan = false;
    var likes_count = response.data.length;
    for(i = 0; i < likes_count; i++) {
        if(response.data[i].id === our_page_id) {
            user_is_fan = true;
  console.log(user_is_fan);
            break;
        }
    }
}); },1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the Facebook API offers a like button that you can put in your website and it's directly liked with you fan page. Every time someone like either your fan page or someone click the button on your site the number increase in both. If it's not a button you want you might be able to reuse the java included with it to do exactly what you want.